# "I'm right, aren't I?"

Tags: contractions

My dictionary reports that *aren't* is also an abbreviation for *am not*, when used in questions.

Is this use of *aren't* common? If it is common, are there any differences between the different English dialects?

> Why aren't I being given a pay raise?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, it is common.  The little-seen "amn't" does occur in Irish and Scottish English.

Comment: +1 for something I didn't know. amn't I lucky

Comment: It's good to note that "ain't" originally meant the same thing as "amn't" before its meaning shifted to mean "is not" and was eventually banned from formal English. Since we need something to fill its gap and amn't never caught on we say "aren't" instead.

Answer (score 12):

There is a good article on this at [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contractions_of_negated_auxiliary_verbs_in_English#Etymology):

> *Amn't* as a contraction of *am not* is known from 1618. As the "mn" combination of two nasal consonants is disfavored by many English speakers, the "m" of *amn't* began to be elided, reflected in writing with the new form *an't*. *Aren't* as a contraction for *are not* first appeared in 1675. In non-rhotic dialects, aren't also began to be represented by *an't*.

Lower down the page, there are the following sentences:

> *Aren't* as a contraction for *am not* developed from one pronunciation of *an't* (which itself developed in part from *amn't* - see etymology of *ain't* for further discussion). In non-rhotic dialects, *aren't* and this pronunciation of *an't* are homonyms. For reasons that are unclear, the spelling *aren't* I began to replace *an't I* in the early part of the twentieth century […].

Answer (score 8):

It's perfectly fine.

In the right dialect you'd also get away with "ain't" (which is the same for first, second and third person, singular and plural, conveniently).  But it's widely (UK) considered a bit vulgar.

"..., am I not" tends to give extra stress.

Answer (score 0):

Is it common? Not in my area. It would be considered snobbish to use it. To me, it's unnatural to use *are* with *I*.

I would never say: *I aren't going to do it.*
Nor would I use it in a question: *Aren't I right?* Technically, it's correct but it makes my skin crawl.

Stick with *I'm not* and *Am I not?* ... However I'm also in a region where, as @ijw says, one can use *ain't* without angst.

Comment: I wouldn't say that *aren't I* is a case of using *are* with *I*.  Rather it uses *aren't* as a contraction of *am not* (which is admittedly questionable).  People who say *Aren't I right?* would (probably) never say *Are I right?*; they'd say *Am I right?*

Comment: @KeithThompson But it is a case of using *are* with *I*. Which is why so many hesitate and wonder about it.  It's simply an artificial creation because *someone* writing a grammar guide somewhen in time took a disliking to amn't, ant, and ain't and they became "non-standard".  I don't use it. It feels wrong, fake, and snobbish. I don't recommend it either.

Comment: So, you're proposing that "Am I not right?" is the _less_ snobbish variant?

Comment: My neighbor uses aren't I all the time. Is she snobbish? I think so; she behaves quite high class.

Answer (score 0):

The original form ‘amn’t I’ as an abbreviation of *am I not* is first recorded in England in the early 1600s, and remains in use in its original form in Ireland and Scotland. In England the consonant cluster mn was considered difficult and the m was further elided so that it became ‘an’t I?’

But in England another complication arose: as the pronunciation of the letter r was dropped in words like hair and care ‘an’t I?’ sounded like the words aren’t I but with a silent r (ahnt I). So the double abbreviation ‘an’t I? sounded like the ungrammatical ‘aren’t I?’ and then that became the accepted, if errant, version of ‘an’t I’.

Most educated speakers in Ireland still say ‘amn’t I’ although some have adopted the ‘aren’t I’ version.