# "Why aren't I afraid?"

Tags: grammar, american-english, contraction-vs-full-form

I came across this sentence in an e book. "Why aren't I afraid?"  Is this the proper way to phrase the question?

Comment: Yes, indeed, it is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I'm right, aren't I?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/im-right-arent-i) and others, including http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34452/is-arent-i-correct-grammar and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29299/why-aint-i-and-arent-i-instead-of-amnt-i

Comment: "More correct" would be "Why am I not afraid?", but that doesn't flow off the tongue nearly as smoothly.  (I've occasionally reflected that English strangely lacks the contraction "amn't".)

Answer (score -1):

Yes. It is an exception: I am not in questions traditionally changes to aren't I. Present-day usage tends to forget about this rule.